# AFNetworking miss implemetation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking-2

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager has this implementation:

```
 - (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation         *operation, NSError *error))failure
 {
     AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
     operation.responseSerializer = self.responseSerializer;
     operation.shouldUseCredentialStorage = self.shouldUseCredentialStorage;
     operation.credential = self.credential;
     operation.securityPolicy = self.securityPolicy;

     [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

     return operation;
 }
```

when use this method, the success and failure blocks never get call.  After I put this line in the implementation:

```
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

it works.  Why AFNetworking 2.0 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager miss this line or I just don't understand this method?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` creates an operation, but does not execute it. When you add the operation to the operation queue you created with this call:

```
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

you are essentially executing the operation you just created. Then the success and failure blocks will get called.

Comment: Also, if the OP doesn't need to use an operation queue, `[operation start]` will work.